# How to call a function when its pointer is stored in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pthreads

How do i call the function in the following example.

i have a struct

```
struct Timing_Thread_Struct {
    int SleepTime;
    void (*Timing_Function)(int);
};
```

I have  function where i fill the structure and create a thread

```
struct Timing_Thread_Struct timing_struct;
timing_struct.SleepTime = 30;
timing_struct.Timing_Function = ExampleFunction;
pthread_create(&delay_thread, NULL, Delay_Thread_Function, (void *)&timing_struct);
pthread_detach( delay_thread);
```

Example Function is

```
void ExampleFunction(int event) {
    //Turn on a digital channel
}
```

Finally my Delay_Thread_Function

```
void *Delay_Thread_Function(void *arguments)
{
    struct Timing_Thread_Struct *timing_struct = arguments;
    msleep(timing_struct -> SleepTime );

    //How do i call the function here?

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

How do i call the function stored in the struct?

i have tried

```
timing_struct->Timing_Function(1);
```

and it just crashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thread `a` creates `struct Timing_Thread_Struct timing_struct;` and fires up thread `b`, then returns, destroying `timing_struct` in the process. Thread `b` attempts to access `timing_struct`, which is destroyed, and gets garbage as a result. It is a common error to assume that `timing_struct` lasts for longer than the thread created below it.

This is likely remedied by using `pthread_join` to suspend execution of the calling thread.

Comment: I have printf the timing->sleeptime just before I call the function and its value is what I set it to when creating the structure. Is your theory still possible?

Comment: My theory is still possible (and most probable) until you paste the entire [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In fact, the delay caused by `printf` (not to mention the `msleep`) will probably make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it did not crash, instead it just quit very quickly. So I think it is not the issue of function pointer in the struct. To confirm this yourself, try adding `pthread_join(delay_thread, NULL);` before calling `pthread_detach` and see whether it is still 'crash' or now working as your original intention.

Comment: Could you please add more information, for example the reason why to do so!? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in other answers you are relying on the existence of the `timing_struct` variable but this might not be true.

If you are OK with [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_join.html)-ing the thread this should do e.g:

```
pthread_join(delay_thread, NULL); // instead of detach
```

See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d4b37feb62cc426)

Otherwise (if you have to detach) you should somehow guarantee the existence of the the struct e.g you could make a local copy and guard the process with a [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) and signal back using a [conditional](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool created = false; // it's global just to make the example minimal 
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

struct Timing_Thread_Struct {
    int SleepTime;
    void (*Timing_Function)(int);
};    

void ExampleFunction(int event) { printf("Hi it's %d\n", event);}        

void *Delay_Thread_Function(void *arguments)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    struct Timing_Thread_Struct timing_struct = *((struct Timing_Thread_Struct*)arguments);
    created = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    // now this thread has it's own copy of the struct so the calling thread can end safely
    timing_struct.Timing_Function(timing_struct.SleepTime);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void){
    struct Timing_Thread_Struct timing_struct;
    pthread_t delay_thread;    
    timing_struct.SleepTime = 30;
    timing_struct.Timing_Function = ExampleFunction;
    pthread_create(&delay_thread, NULL, Delay_Thread_Function, (void *)&timing_struct);
    pthread_detach(delay_thread);


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(!created){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0352ca1f4a87b8f9)